# How to get rid of black lines after ambient occlusion?

Tags: ambient-occlusion

there!
I was finishing my first 3D model and when I was working on it's roughness, I've noticed these weird black lines (formed by black dots). I've tried changing ambient occlusion margin and shaping  its UV map.
Do you know anyway to fix this?
UPD: Looks like it is actually a normal map what is causing the problem

*Black lines*
[image]

*UV map of these parts*
[image]

*With normal map*
[image]

*Without normal map*
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, it seems like I've found a solution to my problem. Basically: there were small odd pixels on my normal map that caused those black lines/dots to appear. So I've "fixed" the map in photoshop by using "Stamp" tool and coloring those pixels.
It seemed to fix the problem.

*"Weird pixels" (cyan pixels among the purple)*
[image]

*After clean up*
[image]

*Overall result*
[image]